# How do I implement a trigger that updates a column of another table?

Tags: sql, triggers, erd

Here is a car rental ERD I designed.
[image]

I'm trying to create an SQL trigger that updates CAR table and SET Car_Status to 'Unavailable' whenever a reservation is made that matches the Car_ID in Car table and Car_ID in Reservation table.

Also if possible I want to add additional conditions where the it updates to 'Available' if the current system date and time is not within the Hire_StartTime and Hire_Endtime in Reservation and does not fall on the same day of Inv_Date in Invoice table.

Basically I want the Car_Status to be set as available if the current system date and time does not fall on the same day **AND** within the hire time of reservation of the car.

I'm sorry if this sounds a bit confusing, english is not my first language I'm new to SQL and not very familiar as to how it works.

If there is a better way of doing this than using trigger, please tell me how. Thank you.

Comment: I really wouldn't do this as a  trigger.  When a reservation is made is that being done through a stored procedure?  If so I would do all the other updates as part of a stored procedure as well.

Comment: can you show me an example of how to do that?

Comment: A general rule of thumb is not to *store* derived data. You can derive this status, at any time, using the logic you're presenting. All you do by storing it is introduce the opportunity for it to be *inconsistent*.